# Routing to Google Map services issue

Tags: google-maps

I'm developing an Android application on a tablet that **must** use both Ethernet (trough USB adapter) and internal LTE carrier (or WiFi) to access *Google Map* services.
When I connect the USB/Ethernet adapter the application becomes unable to authenticate on *Google Map* services and therefore map is not populated at all, when USB is unplugged the application works correctly and *Google Map* component correctly shows its content up to the maximum level of detail.

May this depend on a routing issue? How can I fix this?

BTW the Ethernet port on this device is used **only** to access other devices located on a private LAN whose network is known.

PS The device is a *Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 8.0 t719* running **Android 7.0**.

-- UPDATE --

I'm not certain of the missing authentication since USB port is busy and I cannot see app `logcat` dump in realtime but the behaviour is the same I can observe if *Google Map* authentication fails for some other reason (i.e. WiFi turned off while debugging, invalid *Google Map API* key etc).

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Comment: @Robert Nope. But if needed I can try to root it.